# Gradle task which depends on bootRun

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I have two mutually exclusive tasks that both should launch `bootRun` when they are complete.

I mention that they are mutually exclusive because I don't want `bootRun` to depend on either of them.  Instead, I am looking for a flow similar to the following:

```
task A() {
   // setup for task A
   // runs bootRun on completion
}

task B() {
   // Does some things
   // runs bootRun on completion
}
```

I've tried the following,

```
task C() {
 // Performs the task A setup
}

task A() {
 dependsOn 'C'
 dependsOn 'bootRun'
}
```

so that `gradle A` would launch the setup (`task C`) and bootRun (with a similar setup for `task B`).  This results in `Task with path 'bootRun' not found in project ':x'`

I've also tried declaring the A/B tasks as:
`task A(type: org.springframework.boot.gradle.run.BootRunTask)`, but that results in the error `Could not get unknown property 'org' for project ':x' of type org.gradle.api.Project`

How can I write a task in gradle that will launch bootRun when it completes?

Edit:

This is a multi-module setup which looks something like:

```
settings.gradle
build.gradle
Application module
   build.gradle (spring boot plugin lives here)
   main() lives here
Service module
   build.gradle (this is where tasks A and B live)
```

The spring boot plugin is provided in the Application module's build.gradle via:

```
plugins {
   id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.0.RELEASE'
}
```

I can add this same plugin to the Service module as well, though it won't know what the main class is.

Comment: it looks like you have an issue with how Spring Boot plugin is applied in your project, seeing your error message `Task with path 'bootRun' not found in project ':x'` .  Can you share some details on your project setup? (is it a multi-module project? how do you apply plugins? )

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Updated my post based on your feedback.

Comment: that's what I though: you try to reference task 'bootRun' task in `Service` project, but since SpringBoot plugin is not applied to this project, Gradle complains with the "task not found" error.  Try to reference the `bootRun` task from Appliction project using `:projectPath:taskName` syntax , e.g. `:application:bootRun` in your case . (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks )

Comment: the given answer with the use of `finalizedBy` is correct, but you need to fix your issue with task path since bootRun task is in another project thatn tasks A & B

Comment: @M.Ricciuti that solved my issue, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need finalizedBy(https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:finalizer_tasks)

```
A.finalizedBy bootRun
B.finalizedBy bootRun
```